# how to make 100% layout in blogspot?

Tags: html, css, blogger, blogspot

I am using blog spot default layout, what i want to make to create full Page (100%) width Page. Not sure where do i include css / js in http://webimportance.blogspot.in/

```
<style>
.main-inner {
  width:100%;
  border:2px solid #f00;
}
</style>
```

Appreciate your help

Thanks!

Comment: Inspect element an play around with the classes and you will find it. Take a look at .content-outer, .content-fauxcolumn-outer, .region-inner{}

Comment: I dont get what exactly you want to achieve. Could you explain that a bit more in detail? Or at least somehow 'better'?

Answer (score 1):

You have this class: `content-outer`

```
.content-outer, .content-fauxcolumn-outer, .region-inner {
    min-width: 960px;
    max-width: 960px;
    _width: 960px;
}
```

You need modify to get the 100% for example:

```
.content-outer, .content-fauxcolumn-outer, .region-inner {
    width: 100%;
}
```